# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration in python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm trying to change all the values of F to 1 and the values of M to 0 so I can create a dummy variable and then check the importance of Gender in my predicted results.  I created a dictionary this way

```
Gender_dict = df_new.set_index("Student_ID") ["Gender"].to_dict() 

print (Gender_dict)
```

and got:

```
{366: 'F', 375: 'F', 381: 'F', 391: 'M', 399: 'M', 427: 'M', 429: 'M', 431: 'M', 435: 'M', 444: 'M', 452: 'F', 464: 'M', 472: 'F', 478: 'M', 484: 'F', 487: 'M', 495: 'M', 507: 'F', 1511: 'M', 1512: 'M', 1517: 'F', 1521: 'M', 1526: 'M', 1532: 'F', 1534: 'M', 1540: 'M', 1554: 'M', 1574: 'M', 1576: 'F', 1580: 'M', 1581: 'F', 1592: 'F', 1594: 'F', 1634: 'F', 1638: 'M', 1639: 'M', 1651: 'M', 1672: 'M', 2550: 'M', 7311: 'M', 7313: 'M', 7327: 'M', 7356: 'M', 7361: 'F', 7366: 'M', 7367: 'M', 7372: 'M', 7382: 'M', 7436: 'M', 7440: 'M', 7446: 'M', 8305: 'M', 8312: 'M', 8320: 'M', 8340: 'M', 8342: 'M', 8358: 'M', 8361: 'M', 8363: 'M', 8371: 'M', 8381: 'M', 8383: 'F', 8386: 'F', 8390: 'M', 8391: 'M', 8426: 'M', 8428: 'F', 8435: 'M', 8440: 'M', 8452: 'M', 8457: 'M', 9447: 'M', 9478: 'F', 9486: 'F', 9489: 'M', 9540: 'M', 9545: 'M', 9546: 'M'}
```

I thought this might work

```
for Student_ID, Gender in Gender_dict.items():
    if Gender == "F":
        Gender_dict[Gender] = "1"
    elif Gender == "M":
        Gender_dict[Gender] = "0"

print (Gender_dict)
```

But I get this error:

```
RuntimeError                              
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-acce392dae9f> in <module>()
      5         #a1[color] = "Tulip"
      6 
----> 7 for Student_ID, Gender Gender_dict.items():

      8     if Gender == "F":
      9         Gender_dict[Gender] = "1"

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I tried adapting what I found to suit my purpose but can't get it to work.
I also tried just about every `.replace()` and `.apply()` method I could find but nothing seems to work so I thought this would work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do like `Gender_dict[Student_ID]`, I guess you can do this without iterating using pandas.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a lookup dictionary:

```
gender_lookup = { 'F' : 1, 'M' : 0 }
```

Then you can update your other dictionary using a dictionary comprehension:

```
updated = { student_id : gender_lookup[gender] for student_id,gender in Gender_dict.items() }
```

Answer (score 2):

when iterating on a dictionary, it's perfectly all right to *change* values associated to an *existing* key.

What you cannot do is: add or remove keys.

You're accidentally doing this by using the *value* of the dictionary as the key, creating extra keys and generating the error message.

Generally, this kind of *full dict update* is better done using a dictionary comprehension, overriding the old dictionary:

```
Gender_dict = {Student_ID:"1" if Gender == "F" else "M" for Student_ID, Gender in Gender_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you're doing one-hot encoding by hand, you just have typo in key name

```
for Student_ID, Gender in Gender_dict.items(): 
    if Gender == "F": 
        Gender_dict[Student_ID] = "1" 
    elif Gender == "M": 
        Gender_dict[Student_ID] = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message suggests, you can't mutate a dict while you iterate over its items. You can iterate over a copy of the dict instead:

```
for Student_ID, Gender in list(Gender_dict.items()):
```

Comment: that will just not crash but create keys OP doesn't need. OP error is to use value as key.